# wso2 metadata.xml validUntil

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Our ws02 metadata that is available via the url (https://ourserver:9443/identity/metadata/saml2) has a "validUntil" date on it that is only a few hours long. This causes some issues with Service providers that only refresh the metadata url periodically. Is there a way to change the validUntil time on the metadata in the url so it can be longer?

WSO2 Identity Server 5.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSO2 IS 5.3.0 does not support configuring SAML metadata validity time out of the box. But this feature has been added through a WUM update. You can find the public PRs for this feature in [1] and [2]. If you don't have WUM you can get the this fix by building the product from the public branch[3].

[1] https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity-framework/pull/1980

[2] https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-metadata-saml2/pull/29

[3] https://github.com/wso2/product-is